# "have one player less" or "have one player fewer"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which word is gramatically correct to use in the following sentence, *fewer* or *less*.

> The team has lost because it had one player **less**/**fewer**.

I have definitely heard a native English speaker use the word *less* in similar context, but don't we use *less* with uncountable nouns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ten players.**

**Nine players are less than ten players**. Nine  players are **one less** player than ten. Nine players are **one player less** than ten.

one less player or one player less is nine. One more or additional player is eleven.

**One more** or **one less** expressed as one player more or one more player OR one player less and one less player.

In this context, ***one player fewer*** is **not idiomatic or grammatical**.

Fewer players [a comparative] is grammatical. "Fewer players [than some number] were needed at the last game". One player less would be nine, and that's fine.

Fewer is comparative. Less is not for the collocation: one more, one less are not comparative here.

Comment: So the use of of "fewer" is totally incorect in my sentence, am I right?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Yes, it is wrong in: to have one player fewer. We had fewer players this year than last year. This year we had one less player. All I can do is repeat the same thing. :)

Comment: Eh.  It should be *fewer*, as in **"Nine players are *fewer* than ten players"** ... but as I also think I'm on the losing side of this battle, I'm not going to argue.  English changes by how it's *used*, not by how it's *supposed* to be used.

Comment: No, it is not a comparative here. It is "one less player": The team lost because it had one less player. The word one is what makers the difference: **Nine players are one less than ten players** (not comparative, arithmetical). Versus: **Nine players are fewer than ten players**. (comparative) This is not an English changes issue at all in this case.

Answer (score 0):

*Technically*, you should use "fewer" for countable objects like players.  In practice, it could go either way.  Take for example this tyical supermarket sign:

[image]

"Items" are countable (obviously, otherwise how would you know if you had more than 10), so this sign makes some people irrationally upset, because it's not *strictly* grammatical.  It should be "10 items or *fewer*".

This kind of thing is commonplace, so fighting for proper grammar is a losing battle.  We just have to deal with it.

Comment: Ten items or less than ten items. [not a comparative]. Fewer items are OK when it is a comparative. Fewer people [than last year] attended the game this year.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction between 'less' and 'fewer' is one of usage and is answered in the following dictionary entry: [less](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/less)

> **Fewer** is used with nouns that can be counted. [...] **Less** is usually used with nouns that cannot be counted. [...] [Less] is also used instead of fewer with other sorts of plural nouns, although many people still consider this use incorrect.
>
> Less than 10 people showed up. = Fewer than 10 people showed up.

This is the same sense as in your example, so indeed you can use either 'less' or 'fewer':

> The team lost because it had one player **less** than the other team had.
>
> The team lost because it had one player **fewer** than the other team had.

In this situation you probably would omit the last part in this situation, because that part is understood in this context:

> The team lost because it had one player less.
>
> = They had one player less.

However, the omission does not affect your choice of using 'fewer' or 'less'. Saying the same thing while using 'fewer' is equally valid. Some would even say it is *more* valid because 'fewer' is used with countable nouns:

> The team lost because it had one player fewer.
>
> = They had one player fewer.